# Procedure Specifying More Fields Than I'm Sending

Tags: .net, sql

I have a grid view which I'm running from a SQL datasource.

The select command is a fairly long query. The update command is a stored procedure, which only updates some of the select query's fields. For some reason, though, when I run the update, .Net is appending some of the other select query fields onto the stored procedure call.

I've done a work-around (added the extra fields into the stored procedure), but I'd like to know WHY it's doing this here (I've used remarkably similar code in about ten other places with no issues) and what I can do to permanently remove the extraneous fields.

This is my data source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="CONNECT STRING" 
SelectCommand="SELECT TID, CIName, TTDesc, TLA, TDesc, TDel = Case When (Select Count(PAID) from PropertyAttribute where PropertyAttribute.TID=T.TID)=0 then 'delete.gif' else 'onepixblank.gif' End, 'transportdel.asp?TID=' + Convert(varchar(10),TID) as TDelLink  FROM Transport T, CountryID C, TransportType TT where T.TType=TT.TType and T.CIID=C.CIID and TT.CIID=C.CIID order by C.CIID, TT.TType, TDesc" 
UpdateCommand="TransportUpdate" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TID" Type="Int32"
        <asp:Parameter Name="TDesc" Type="String"
        <asp:Parameter Name="TLA" Type="String"
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserName" Name="UName" PropertyName="Text />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about insertion ? You don't have to set an InsertCommand ? I'm not often using automatically filled grid from a DataSource (prefer have control on what happens), but I think InsertCommand is automatically generated from the SelectCommand. Maybe that's it in your case : it's not an update but an insert ? Or maybe I am completely wrong ?

Comment: Nope - it's definitely not an insert (that's done elsewhere and handled separately), which is also why there is no insert statement.